# SQL query - cost of using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization, distinct

Does the use of DISTINCT have a lot of influence on the query cost of a SQL query's execution plan?

On a table with 100,000 rows, what difference will there be between:

```
select * from TABLE
```

and

```
select distinct(*) from TABLE
```

in term of milliseconds?

Comment: If you have a key on that table, there wouldn't be any difference between the two.  Since you're selecting all fields the key would make each row distinct

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: I think it will be some difference cos distinct checks if there is or not any difference, but select all not.

Comment: There will be a major difference. The database will have to sort or hash all rows over all columns. Just look at the execution plan and you will see. There is no way to quantify the additional cost in terms of milliseconds though. Depends on your hardware, the number of columns and the data types of the columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the answer is *many* milliseconds.  The `select distinct` is equivalent to doing a `group by` on all the columns.  It is unlikely that you have an index on all the columns, so an index will not generally be very useful.

Some database engines might be smart enough to detect if one of the columns is declared `distinct` or a `primary key`.  In that case, there might be an engine that optimizes the query.

But, in general, you should avoid using `select distinct` unless you need to.